# Can HttpListener Class being Used for sniffing?

Tags: c#, http, packet, packet-sniffers

I just found HttpListener Class , I have read the API on MSDN but I still don't get something:
can HTTPListener being used to sniff the incomming/outgoing Requests*?

I mean to sniff all the HTTP & maybe HTTPS packets on my network card , all I would like to retrieve is a simply URL of visited sites.

Comment: Uh... no? Link to where you read this?

Comment: @AngeloGeels: I didn't found that I can use it as sniffer, but I have read it uses http.sys driver, which can be used to hook HTTP and maybe even HTTPS requests, so I just asked here if it is possible.

Comment: what packets are you trying to sniff just http port 80? or all packets going through your Network Card, or all packets going through the LAN?  sniffing question, isn't specific enough

Comment: @MichaelEvanchik Edited the question: specified what I would to sniff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: No.

The long answer is: The HTTPListener-class is used to create a very basic webserver on which you can implement your own methods and services. You might be able to use it to [write a proxy](http://johnstewien.wordpress.com/2009/12/21/httplistener-proxy/) and route your http requests through it though but I'm pretty sure that wasn't the main intention of it.

Comment: Thank you, yes I just implemented 2 sniffers 1 by rawsockets and 1 by winPcaP

all I use them is to log http requests (more accurate is urls).
I thought maybe this class can help me to do so more elegant, Well thank you for your answer appreciate that :) have a nice day !

Comment: the proxy is the way you want to go if its just http.  but you can get around proxy servers, via vpn's etc.  winsock hook (although more then you want) is the sure way to catch any outbound traffic.